# Best Practice for displaying logo larger than navigation bar

Tags: html, css, web, navbar, graphical-logo

my question is:

If I want to display a 100px by 100px logo on the left of my nav bar, but my nav bar has only 50px height... How should I design the html  structures and css rules ?

Right now I use:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <ul id="nav">
    <a id="logo" href="#" ></a>
    <li><a href="#"</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"</a></li>
    </ul><!-- #nav -->
</div><!-- #header-wrapper-->
</div><!-- #header -->
```

Where CSS codes are:

```
#header {
height: 50px;
position: relative;
border-bottom: 5px solid #e5dacd;
background: #1075bc;
margin-bottom: 60px;}

#header-wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 940px;}

#logo {
width:  100px;
height: 100px;
background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat;
background-color: yellow;
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;}

#nav {
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 16px 0 0 0;}
```

Is there any better way to do the trick ? (in terms of flexibility or compatibility to future modifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices - set the logo to `position: absolute` and position it where you need it, this way it won't be constrained to it's parent's height.

Or you can try to give it negative margins and make sure that `overflow` for the header is not `hidden`